# Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I am trying to produce a simple scripting system that will be used to print labels. I have done this in the past with reflection with no problem, but I am now trying to do it with Lambda functions so that I can cache the functions for reuse.

The code I have so far is as follows...

```
public static string GetValue<T>(T source, string propertyPath) {

    try {

        Func<T, Object> func;

        Type type = typeof(T);
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(type, @"source");
        Expression expression = parameterExpression;
        foreach (string property in propertyPath.Split('.')) {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(property);
            expression = Expression.Property(expression, propertyInfo);
            type = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        }

        func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Object>>(expression, parameterExpression).Compile();

        object value = func.Invoke(source);
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;
        return value.ToString();

    }
    catch {

        return propertyPath;

    }

}
```

This seems to work in some cases, but in others it fails. The problem seems to be in my trying to return the values as objects - irrespective of the actual data types. I am trying to do this because I do not know at compile time what the data type will be but in the long run, I only need a string.

I am getting the exception shown in the title of this message whenever I try to access a property of type Int32 - but I am also getting it for Nullable types and others.
 The exception is thrown when I try to compile the expression into the function.

Can anybody suggest how I might go about this differently whilst maintaining the Lambda functionality so that I can cache the accessors?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Have you tried using [Expression.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx)? That will add the boxing/lifting/etc conversion.

```
Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(object));
func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Object>>(conversion, parameterExpression).Compile();
```

Comment: You were extremely close with this answer, only it was "expression" that needed to be converted and not "parameterExpression" (expression = Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(Object));
) just before the compilation.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you a lot! :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: How would you do the same thing for a property setter? I've tried every Expression operation I can think of to convert in the other direction but nothing quite works?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: I suggest you ask a new question with a complete example of what you're trying to do. Most of the time you'd want to use a property chain where all but the last expression is still a getter - and just the *last* part is a setter. But it's hard to be more concrete than that without an example to try to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Student
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var student = new Student();
            PrintProperty(student, "Name");
            PrintProperty(student, "Age");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void PrintProperty<T>(T obj, string propName)
        {
            PrintProperty<T, object>(obj, propName);
        }

        private static void PrintProperty<T, TProperty>(T obj, string propName)
        {
            ParameterExpression ep = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            MemberExpression em = Expression.Property(ep, typeof(T).GetProperty(propName));
            var el = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TProperty>>(Expression.Convert(em, typeof(object)), ep);
            Console.WriteLine(GetValue(obj, el));
        }

        private static TProperty GetValue<T, TProperty>(T obj, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            return expression.Compile().Invoke(obj);
        }

        public class Student
        {
            public Student()
            {
                Name = "Albert Einstein";
                Age = 15;
            }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```