# Building an OrderBy expression using the name of a property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, expression-trees

I'm trying to support sorting via the `WebGrid` control in MVC3, which passes the name of a property on my model into my actions via a `sort` parameter.

```
public class Agent {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string sort = "Id", string sortdir = "ASC") {

    // Define the parameter that we are going to use in the OrderBy clause.
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Agent), "agent");

    // Now we'll make our lambda function that returns the
    // property's value by it's name.
    var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Agent, object>>(Expression.Property(param, sort), param);

    var agents = entities.OrderBy(sortExpression).ToList();

    var model = new PagedResult<Agent> {

        CurrentPage = 1,
        PageCount = 1,
        PageSize = DefaultPageSize,
        Results = agents,
        RowCount = agents.Count

    };

    return View(model);
}
```

This code works when I try to sort my model by the `Name` property, which is of type `string`. However, if I try to sort by `Id` I receive the error `Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'`.

Comment: have you tried using Expression.Convert as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200209/expression-of-type-system-int32-cannot-be-used-for-return-type-system-object/2200247#2200247

Comment: I just got it working using `Expression.TypeAs`. I'm not sure what the difference between the two is yet, but if you want to submit that as an answer I'll be more than happy to give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `Expression.Convert` to perform Boxing.