# Expression of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, expression

I've created an expression that I'm using for sorting which works fine, until I hit a `DateTime` field, where I get the following error (on the second line):

> Expression of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be used for return type
>   'System.Object'

Here's my code:

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyEntity), "x");

Expression<Func<MyEntity, object>> sortExpression =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<AMyEntity, object>>(
        Expression.Property(param, sortKey), param);
```

Can anyone help at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200209/expression-of-type-system-int32-cannot-be-used-for-return-type-system-object)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just add a conversion in there:

```
Expression<Func<MyEntity, object>> sortExpression =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<AMyEntity, object>>(
        Expression.Convert(
            Expression.Property(param, sortKey),
            typeof(object)),
        param);
```

Answer (score 16):

You appear to be expecting auto-boxing of value-types to match the return-type of the expression. Unfortunately, `Expression.Lambda` does not do this.

You can use [`Expression.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx) to perform the boxing.

```
var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, sortKey), typeof(object));
var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<AMyEntity, object>>(body, param);
```

If for some reason you don't want the conversion operation to be present in the expression if the property is already a reference-type, you can branch as required:

```
Expression body = Expression.Property(param, sortKey);

if(body.Type.IsValueType)
   body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
```