# LINQ Dynamic sort with nullable fields

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dynamic sort mechanism which I am using to do a dyanmic LINQ OrderBy. This works fine on ordinary fields.

```
string sortField = "MyField"
var orderByParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyType), "MyType");
var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyType, object>>(Expression.Property(orderByParam, sortField), orderByParam);
```

However when I try to use a Nullable field (which happens to be a DateTime) I get the following error:

> Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' cannot be used
>   for return type 'System.Object'

How can I get round this?

Comment: Have you tried using an `Expression.Convert` to cast the `DateTime?` to `object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert it to an object first. This has nothing to do with nullable field. I.E.:

```
string sortField = "MyField";
var orderByParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyType), "MyType");
var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyType, object>>(
  Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(orderByParam, sortField), 
  typeof(object)), orderByParam);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a dupe of [Expression of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974837/expression-of-type-system-datetime-cannot-be-used-for-return-type-system-obje) and [Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200209/expression-of-type-system-int32-cannot-be-used-for-return-type-system-object)

basically you cant do this for any value type (including nullable) as you need to explicitly box

see the accepted answer to the first link.