# Why is Guid NOT an object in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, expression-trees

I just got the following exception, which seems to indicate that `Guid` is not an object.

> Expression of type 'System.Guid' cannot be used for return type
>   'System.Object'

How is `Guid` not an object?

And how does the compiler figure this out? There must be something that would allow me to detect at runtime when a type is not an object, if so what would this be?

====================Edit with additional info====================

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(SomeExpression)
```

Where SomeExpression could be a constant value of a Guid, for all that matters.

Comment: This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200209/expression-of-type-system-int32-cannot-be-used-for-return-type-system-object

Comment: Yes it is, but I don't want to cast un necessarily, how would I know if something will work out of the bat? The expression works ok, until I deal with the native/value type of stuff.

Comment: Your question missing sample code (and preferably CSXXXX error code with link to MSDN, so you can comment on what is not clear).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(SomeExpression)
```

The problem here is that you are using expression trees incorrectly. Even though the box operation is implicit in C#, it still exists. It is **not** implicit in expression trees. The following should fix it:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(
    Expression.Convert(SomeExpression, typeof(object))
```

You could also check `SomeExpression.Type.IsValueType` to decide whether or not to add this additional explicit conversion.

Comment: Marc, the implicit conversion has been working ok, until I deal with Guid. It works fine with my dictionary, list, custom complex class - you name it. I don't think Guid is the only exception, but it's definitely one of them.

Comment: @Alwyn and everything you mention is a *reference type*. As I said: the box operation must be explicit. `Guid` is a *value type* (a `struct`)

Comment: @MarcGravell Gotcha, that'd explain a lot of things, so you need boxing for value types. All reference types get a free pass.

Comment: @Alwyn yes; the point is that the conversion from (say) `SomeClass` to `object` is value-preserving: it is **exactly** the same value in and out - a trivial no-op. That is very different to a box, which must be represented explicitly.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks this is the answer I'm looking for, can you give me a hint as to where I can learn a bit more abt some of the terminologies you used? I admit some of them sounds a bit foreign. What's a trivial "no-op" and the difference to a "box"?

Comment: @Alwyn I think this addresses both: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx