# Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'Boolean Equals(System.Object)'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

i have one common grid view column filter method that filter grid view record with ColumnName and SearchText wise. here when i operate on nullable int datacolumn there is error thrown from this method like :

> Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'Boolean Equals(System.Object)'

my method code is :

```
 public static IQueryable<T> FilterForColumn<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, string colName, string searchText)
{
    if (colName != null && searchText != null)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
        var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, colName);
        System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression searchExpression = null;
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo containsMethod = null;
        // this must be of type Expression to accept different type of expressions
        // i.e. BinaryExpression, MethodCallExpression, ...
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body = null;
        Expression ex1 = null;
        Expression ex2 = null;
        switch (colName)
        {
            case "JobID":
            case "status_id":
                Int32 _int = Convert.ToInt32(searchText);
                searchExpression = Expression.Constant(_int);
                containsMethod = typeof(Int32).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(Int32) });
                body = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, searchExpression);
                break;
            case "group_id":
                Int32? _int1 = Convert.ToInt32(searchText);
                searchExpression = Expression.Constant(_int1);
                containsMethod = typeof(Int32?).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(Int32?) });                     
                //Error throws from this line
                body = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, searchExpression);


                break;
            case "FileSize":
            case "TotalFileSize":
                Int64? _int2 = Convert.ToInt64(searchText);
                searchExpression = Expression.Constant(_int2);
                containsMethod = typeof(Int64?).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(Int64?) });
                body = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, searchExpression);
                break;
            // section for DateTime? properties
            case "PublishDate":
            case "Birth_date":
            case "Anniversary_date":
            case "Profile_Updated_datetime":
            case "CompletedOn":
                DateTime currentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(searchText, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                DateTime nextDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
                ex1 = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(currentDate, typeof(DateTime?)));
                ex2 = Expression.LessThan(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(nextDate, typeof(DateTime?)));
                body = Expression.AndAlso(ex1, ex2);
                break;
            // section for DateTime properties
            case "Created_datetime":
            case "Reminder_Date":
            case "News_date":
            case "thought_date":
            case "SubscriptionDateTime":
            case "Register_datetime":
            case "CreatedOn":
                DateTime currentDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(searchText, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                DateTime nextDate1 = currentDate1.AddDays(1);
                ex1 = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(currentDate1));
                ex2 = Expression.LessThan(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(nextDate1));
                body = Expression.AndAlso(ex1, ex2);
                break;
            default:
                searchExpression = Expression.Constant(searchText);
                containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
                body = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, searchExpression);
                break;
        }
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, new[] { parameter });
        return queryable.Where(predicate);
    }
    else
    {
        return queryable;
    }
}
```

here is my query that i fired :

```
var query = Helper.GetUsers().Where(u => u.Id != user_id).OrderByDescending(u => u.Register_datetime).Select(u => new
                  {
                      Id = u.Id,
                      Name = u.First_name + " " + u.Last_name,
                      IsActive = u.IsActive,
                      IsVerified = u.IsVerified,
                      Username = u.Username,
                      password = u.password,
                      Birth_date = u.Birth_date,
                      Anniversary_date = u.Anniversary_date,
                      status_id = u.status_id,
                      group_id = u.group_id,
                      Profile_Updated_datetime = u.Profile_Updated_datetime,
                      Register_datetime = u.Register_datetime
                  }).FilterForColumn(ColumnName, SearchText).ToList();
```

here i include my query.GetType().ToString() result for better understanding types of columns that i operate on it.

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`12[System.Int32,System.String,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.DateTime]]
```

Comment: what line is the exception?

Comment: from the body line of group_id case. show updated question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT**

Found the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200209/expression-of-type-system-int32-cannot-be-used-for-return-type-system-object?rq=1). You need to convert the expression to `Object` before calling the `Equals(object)`method:

```
var converted = Expression.Convert(searchExpression, typeof(object));
body = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, converted);
```

[Nicodemus13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26463/nicodemus13)'s suggestion of explicitly setting `searchExpression`'s type to `Object` in the first place should work, too.

**Original**

I haven't found the issue yet, but I have reproduced the problem in a SSCCE using Linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    var myInstance = new myClass();
    var equalsMethod = typeof(Int32?).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(Int32?) });
    int? nullableInt = 1;
    var nullableIntExpr = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(nullableInt);
    var myInstanceExpr = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(myInstance);
    var propertyExpr = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(myInstanceExpr, "MyProperty");
    var result = Expression.Call(propertyExpr,equalsMethod,nullableIntExpr); // This line throws the exception.
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

class myClass{public int? MyProperty{get;set;}}
```

This line:

```
containsMethod = typeof(Int32?).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(Int32?) });
```

returns a `MethodInfo` for the method `Int32?.Equals (Object other)`. Notice the parameter type is `object`, not `Int32` (or `Int32?`) as you might expect.

The reason is `typeof(Int32?)` is `System.Nullable<Int32>`, which only has the `Equals(object)` method.

Comment: this works. but how ever at cases of case FileSize,TotalFileSize i never found any problem like this.

Comment: I think that's because those don't actually appear in your query, so the corresponding `case` statement is never executed.

Comment: Can we face issue like converting to object in case we work with Int64?.

Comment: Yes, the `Int64?`will behave the same way as `Int32?`, so you would need to convert the expression to type `Object` again.

Comment: Because there's no `FileSize` or `TotalFileSize` property in your query. Put a breakpoint in the `case` handling them, and I bet it will not get hit when you run it, so it won't throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

Playing around with this in LinqPad, I think the problem is around:

`searchExpression = Expression.Constant(_int1);`

when you call:

`containsMethod = typeof(Int32?).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(Int32?) });`

The `Equals` method you're attempting to call is `object.Equals(object)` and the compiler is telling you that the type `int?` is not the type `object` that the method expects.

The simplest fix (though I'm not sure that the overall code will work, though this particular error will go away) is to change the overload of the `Expression.Constant` that you call to one that specifies the type that `Equals` expects:

`searchExpression = Expression.Constant(_int1, typeof(object));`

This will compile- however, there's a few things to note.

1. Your original `Expression.Constant(_int1)` results in a `ConstantExpression` with `Type` `int` not `int?`.  You'd need to specify the nullable type, if you needed that (`Expression.Constant(_int1, typeof(int?))`). However, you'll need to cast it to `object` anyway, as above.
2. Specifying `containsMethod = typeof(Int32?).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(Int32?) });` shouldn't work anyway, as there's not such method `int?.Equals(int?)`, the `Equals` method is the override of the method on the `System.Object` class which takes an `object` parameter and is the root of the problem.  You may as well use: `typeof(object).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(object) });` as that's the correct declaration.

As I said, it should compile with `object`, whether the code does what you expect, I'm not sure, but I think so.  I look forward to seeing whether it works :)

Comment: thank u..it's works. but how ever i wonder i don't need this technique used for Int64?.

Comment: You're saying that (your) exactly the same code, but replacing `Int32?` with `Int64?` doesn't throw the original exception?

Comment: not replacing means i have already Int64? which is running fine. why Int32? getting error like that.

Comment: Pass :) I don't know; I can't see why it would work with one and not the other.  Your original code shouldn't work with `Int64?`

Comment: ya i know. Because i think Int64? works with if we are working with bigint. And it is not required for casting to object.