# How to build a dynamic LINQ expression with predicates and nullable booleans

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to create a dynamic where clause to use with the Entity Framework. This is the article that I am following:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493917/Dynamic-Querying-with-LINQ-to-Entities-and-Express

The **Dynamic Where** section in the article is where the explanation and code is.

I created a class with one property to try it out:

```
public class CVLocalFilteringInputDTO
{
    [DbFieldMapAttribute("PersonGenderCode")]
    public Nullable<bool> PersonGenderCode { get; set; }
}
```

The Entity Framework class that I am using has a similar property:

```
     public partial class SearchPSSCitizen {
        ... constructor here ...
        public Nullable<bool> PersonGenderCode { get; set; }
        ... some additional properties here ...
     }
```

In the top of the code there is a method for comparing booleans:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo BooleanEqualsMethod = 
  typeof (bool).GetMethod(@"Equals", BindingFlags.Instance | 
  BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] {typeof (bool)}, null);
```

And the method that uses this function looks like this:

```
private static Expression<Func<TDbType, bool>> ApplyBoolCriterion<TDbType, 
  TSearchCriteria>(TSearchCriteria searchCriteria, PropertyInfo searchCriterionPropertyInfo, 
  Type dbType, MemberInfo dbFieldMemberInfo, Expression<Func<TDbType, bool>> predicate)
{
    // Check if a search criterion was provided
    var searchBool = searchCriterionPropertyInfo.GetValue(searchCriteria) as bool?;
    if (searchBool == null)
    {
        return predicate;
    }
    // Then "and" it to the predicate.
    // e.g. predicate = predicate.And(x => x.isActive.Contains(searchCriterion.IsActive)); ...
    // Create an "x" as TDbType
    var dbTypeParameter = Expression.Parameter(dbType, @"x");
    // Get at x.isActive
    var dbFieldMember = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(dbTypeParameter, dbFieldMemberInfo);
    // Create the criterion as a constant
    var criterionConstant = new Expression[] {Expression.Constant(searchBool)};
    // Create the MethodCallExpression like x.isActive.Equals(criterion)
    var equalsCall = Expression.Call(dbFieldMember, BooleanEqualsMethod, criterionConstant);
    // Create a lambda like x => x.isActive.Equals(criterion)
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(equalsCall, dbTypeParameter) as Expression<Func<TDbType, bool>>;
    // Apply!
    return predicate.And(lambda);
}
```

Since i am not using the primitive type `bool` but `Nullable<bool>`, i changed the BooleanEqualsMethod to:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo BooleanEqualsMethod =
          typeof(Nullable<bool>).GetMethod(@"Equals", BindingFlags.Instance |
          BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(object) }, null);
```

and

```
var searchBool = searchCriterionPropertyInfo.GetValue(searchCriteria) as bool?;
```

to

```
var searchBool = searchCriterionPropertyInfo.GetValue(searchCriteria) as Nullable<bool>;
```

Notice that the Equals method of Nullable takes an `object` type as argument rather than a `bool` type.

When I run the code, the following error occours:

```
Additional information: Expression of type 'System.Boolean' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'Boolean Equals(System.Object)'
```

From [Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'Boolean Equals(System.Object)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077366/expression-of-type-system-int32-cannot-be-used-for-parameter-of-type-system-o) I learned that the expression should be converted to an object type and passed to the Expression.Call method:

```
var converted = Expression.Convert(criterionConstant.First(), typeof(object));
var equalsCall = Expression.Call(dbFieldMember, BooleanEqualsMethod, converted);
```

This does not throw any exceptions and the lambda expression becomes:

```
{x => x.PersonGenderCode.Equals(Convert(False))}
```

However, when I try to query the database with the predicate:

```
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
    var query = db.SearchPSSCitizen.AsExpandable().Where(predicate) as IQueryable<SearchPSSCitizen>; 
    Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
```

I get the following exception:

```
Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

When hovering the predicate in the Where clause, it looks like this:

```
{f => (True AndAlso Invoke(x => x.PersonGenderCode.Equals(Convert(False)), f))}
```

When searching for the exception above, the answer is to change "Equals" to "==", however, I am not sure how to do that in this case.

What should I do to move on and fix this issue?

Comment: have you tried using the `Expression.Equal` instead, don't need to create custom equal method. It of course still requires the 2 operands to have exactly matched type. I understand that `searchBool` is `bool?` so the property should also be `bool?`. If that's correct, I believe you can totally use `Expression.Equal`.

Comment: The Entity Framework decided to use Nullable<bool> so I have to stick with that (for my input class - so that the types match). I just tried with Expression.Equal and it works! :) The "as Nullable<bool>" returns a Boolean instead of a Nullable<bool>, so I still have to use Expression.Convert though. Thank you.