# C# Dynamic lambda problem with implementing "IndexOf" ignore case

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I have been following [pashov.net](http://www.pashov.net/code/dynamic+filters) and in particular his approach to filtering by building dynamic Linq expressions.

I implemented it and it worked but is the string search is case sensitive. Currently it does not have an IndexOf StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase option so I had a go at adding one in.

I get an error once it reached that part of the code where it tries to run the lambda call on it... `return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param);`

It was having trouble converting from int32 to bool.

```
    System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean'
  Source=System.Linq.Expressions
  StackTrace:
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, String paramName)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, ParameterExpression[] parameters)
   at JobsLedger.API.ControllerServices.Shared.OrderAndFIlterHelpers.DynamicFilteringHelper.ConstructAndExpressionTree[T](List`1 filters) in C:\AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.0\JobsLedger.API\ControllerServices\Shared\OrderAndFIlterHelpers\DynamicFilteringHelper.cs:line 48
   at JobsLedger.API.ControllerServices.Shared.ODataFilterAndSort.ParginatedFilteredSorted[T](IQueryable`1 source, String query) in C:\AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.0\JobsLedger.API\ControllerServices\Shared\OrderAndFIlterHelpers\ODataFilterAndSort.cs:line 41
   at JobsLedger.API.ControllerServices.API.App.ClientServices.ClientServices.GetPaginatedClients(String query) in C:\AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.0\JobsLedger.API\ControllerServices\API\App\ClientServices\ClientServices.cs:line 65
   at JobsLedger.API.Controllers.API.App.ClientController.Index(String query) in C:\AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.0\JobsLedger.API\Controllers\API\App\ClientController.cs:line 28
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

I did some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200247/5750758) and it was suggested that it be converted Using `.Convert` but that didn't work as there is no conversion from int32 to bool.

here is the code.

```
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ConstructAndExpressionTree<T>(List<ExpressionFilter> filters) {
            if (filters.Count == 0)
                return null;

            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
            Expression exp = null;

            if (filters.Count == 1) {
                exp = ExpressionRetriever.GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]);
            }
            else {
                exp = ExpressionRetriever.GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]);
                for (int i = 1; i < filters.Count; i++) {
                    exp = Expression.And(exp, ExpressionRetriever.GetExpression<T>(param, filters[i]));
                }
            }

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param); //.. FAILS HERE
        }

    public static class ExpressionRetriever {
        private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
        private static MethodInfo startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        private static MethodInfo endsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });

        public static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, ExpressionFilter filter) {
            MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);
            ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);
            switch (filter.Comparison) {
                case Comparison.Equal:
                    return Expression.Equal(member, constant);
                case Comparison.GreaterThan:
                    return Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);
                case Comparison.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                    return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);
                case Comparison.LessThan:
                    return Expression.LessThan(member, constant);
                case Comparison.LessThanOrEqual:
                    return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);
                case Comparison.NotEqual:
                    return Expression.NotEqual(member, constant);
                case Comparison.Contains:
                    return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, constant);
                case Comparison.StartsWith:
                    return Expression.Call(member, startsWithMethod, constant); 
                case Comparison.IndexOf:
                    var test = Expression.Call(member, "IndexOf", null, Expression.Constant(filter.Value, typeof(string)), Expression.Constant(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));           
                    return test;
                    //return Expression.Convert(test, typeof(bool));
                case Comparison.EndsWith:
                    return Expression.Call(member, endsWithMethod, constant);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

It would be nice if the I could put some code in that didnt require creating a Call as I have done. Is there a way to implement this as a method etc as per the other string options or is the way I tried the only way considering I need an extra parameter..

i.e How can I implement the IndexOf option and return a bool?

Comment: Just want to make sure you know what expression you actually need to construct - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring before digging into the question...

Comment: Yeah, `IndexOf` returns a number (i.e. the index), not a boolean. I'm not sure when you expect this to return true, and when to return false, but I think you might be trying to reimplement `Contains` by another name

Comment: Im actually not that worried about whether its contains Index of etc.. Just need this to be case insensitive for the search.. appreciate the response though.

Comment: Just looked at that question Alexei and yes its case insensitive Im after.. just not sure how to implement this with the current code and dynamic lambda.. Think I might need to add another Expression parameter..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET Core there is an overload of [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-2.1) which allows specifying comparison rules. There you could end up with something like:

```
public static class ExpressionRetriever
{
    private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison)});
    ...

    public static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, ExpressionFilter filter)
    {
        ...
        ConstantExpression comparisonType = Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        switch (filter.Comparison)
        {
            ...
            case Comparison.Contains:
                return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, constant), comparisonType);
        }
    }
}
```

In any other case, you could create a custom compare method which you use in your expression, like:

```
public class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsIgnoringCase(string str, string substring)
    {
        return str.IndexOf(substring, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }
}

...

public static class ExpressionRetriever
{
    ...
    private static MethodInfo containsIgnoringCaseMethod = typeof(StringExtensions).GetMethod("ContainsIgnoringCase", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string)});

    public static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, ExpressionFilter filter)
    {
        ...
        switch (filter.Comparison)
        {
            ...
            case Comparison.Contains:
                return Expression.Call(null, containsIgnoringCaseMethod, member, constant);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only issue with using the custom compare approach is if this is meant to be converted to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for `IndexOf`, the method returns:

> The index position of the value parameter if that string is found, or -1 if it is not.

So in order to check if `Foo.PropertyName` contains `Value`, you need to create the following expression:

```
Foo.PropertyName.IndexOf(Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1
```

This means wrapping all of what you have so far in `Expression.NotEqual(left, right)`:

```
case Comparison.IndexOf:
    return Expression.NotEqual(
        Expression.Call(
            member,
            "IndexOf",
            null,
            Expression.Constant(filter.Value, typeof(string)),
            Expression.Constant(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, typeof(StringComparison))
        ),
        Expression.Constant(-1, typeof(int))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

i did it using ToLower expression first and then the result of this expression was instance parameter in my contains expression exam:

```
    ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");
    MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(arg, field);

    var lowerStringExpression = Expression.Call(property, "ToLower", null);            
    var expression = Expression.Call(lowerStringExpression, "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(value.ToLower(), typeof(string)));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(expression, new ParameterExpression[] { arg });
```