# How to make an unboxing setter expression?

Tags: .net, linq-expressions

I'm using the following code to create an Expression based property setter:

```
Public Function PropertySetExpression(Of TObjectType, TPropertyType)(propertyName As String) As Expression(Of Action(Of TObjectType, TPropertyType))
   Dim paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(TObjectType), "value")
   Dim propertyExpression = Expression.[Property](paramExpression, propertyName)
   Dim getter = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of TObjectType, TPropertyType))(propertyExpression, paramExpression)

   Dim member = CType(getter.Body, MemberExpression)
   Dim param = Expression.Parameter(GetType(TPropertyType), "value")

   Return Expression.Lambda(Of Action(Of TObjectType, TPropertyType))(Expression.Assign(member, param), getter.Parameters(0), param)
End Function
```

And this works perfectly if `TProperty` is specified at compile time. But sometimes I need a more flexible architecture, and want to use `Object` instead of a more specific type, and this *also* works fine if `TProperty` is a reference type. But if it's a value type, I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object''

In [this answer to a similar question, but about a property getter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200247/349974), Jon Skeet explains how to fix this for a property getter, by inserting a Convert expression to box the value type to an object, but I can't figure out how to apply this in the reverse direction to *unbox* the object before setting back into a value type.

How might I do this?

## Update, as requested by comment:

A normal property setter would be something like:

```
obj.Id = 3
```

The above code is so that I could get a function dynamically to accomplish the same thing:

```
Dim setter = PropertySetExpression(Of TMyObject, Integer)("Id").Compile()

...

setter(obj, 3)
```

The reason to do this would be in scenarios where I want to be able to set properties specified in, say, a text file, but with the fast performance of a property setter.

As I say in the post, this works fine. But sometimes I don't even know the data type at compile time, so I want to do:

```
Dim setter = PropertySetExpression(Of TMyObject, Object)(prop_name).Compile()
```

And let the setter deal with the boxing/unboxing from the actual data type (`Integer` in this case) to `Object`.

Comment: Can you show what the C#/VB.NET code would look like if you were to write the code normally?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: Sure, see update. Does that provide what you're looking for?

Comment: So the type for the `Id` property used in the `obj.Id` expression is `object`?