Possible to use LINQ Expression with Delegate Signature to obtain parameters?
Is it possible to obtain ParameterInfo and argument values for a delegate invocation which is inside a (compiler-generated) LambdaExpression?
For example I have defined a delegate:
public class A
{
   public delegate string[] GetInfo(int[] ids);
}

Now I need to use an expression to obtain the parameter values with the PropertyInfo of the delegate parameters. Only way I was able to get the Expression to work is to use it as an Action:
public readonly struct DelegateInfo
{
    public Type ReturnType{ get; }

    public Dictionary<ParameterInfo, object> Parameters { get; }
}

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        var info = GetDelegateInfo<A.GetInfo>(del => del(new int[]{1,2,3}));
    }

    public DelegateInfo GetDelegateInfo<TDelegate>(Expression<Action<TDelegate>> exp)
        where TDelegate : Delegate
    {
        // Get the action of the expression
        var action = exp.Parameters[0];

        // How to obtain the delegate ParameterInfo and values?
        ...

        return new DelegateInfo { ... };
    }
}

Is this the right way to achieve this? Is there a better way?

You mean you want to get int[] ids as a ParameterInfo?

@Sweeper Yes, I want to get the ParameterInfo of the int[] ids along with the values (1, 2, 3).

With updated struct to:
public readonly struct DelegateInfo
{
    public Type ReturnType { get; init; }

    public Dictionary<ParameterInfo, object> Parameters { get; init; }
}

The main trick is to get the Invoke method of the delegate and do something like:
DelegateInfo GetDelegateInfo<TDelegate>(Expression<Action<TDelegate>> exp)
    where TDelegate : Delegate
{
    var type = typeof(TDelegate); // or exp.Parameters[0].Type
    var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Invoke"); // get the invoke method

    // TODO: throw error if not an InvocationExpression
    var invocationExpression = exp.Body as InvocationExpression;
    return new DelegateInfo
    {
        ReturnType = methodInfo.ReturnType,
        Parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters()
            .Zip(invocationExpression.Arguments) // get passed arguments
            .ToDictionary(t => t.Item1, t =>
            {
                var argument = t.Item2;
                // quick and dirty approach - compile and invoke
                // possibly better to visit the expression
                // but will require much more work
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(argument).Compile()();
            })
    };
}


Alternatively, ConstantExpressions could be assumed for the arguments. But this depends on the use case and is very limiting.

this is the core solution, but just wanted to add that nothing guarantees that we have InvocationExpression. We can just have del => Console.WriteLine(42); as the Expression, so a check for the InvocationExpression AND that the InvocaitonExpression is on TDelegate and not something captured.

@IvanPetrov yes, that is a common problem of such APIs working with expression trees - quite often you can't prevent the incorrect usage via type system. Added a small comment to address this.

@GuruStron yeah, no way around that if we want to have ergonomics on the other side. Maybe also add after the invocation type check ->  (invocationExpression.Expression.NodeType==ExpressionType.Parameter) which should be enough to guarantee that we have invoked the parameter.

Have to convert argument to an object expression (value to reference type) var argument = Expression.Convert(t.Item2, typeof(object)) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200209/expression-of-type-system-int32-cannot-be-used-for-return-type-system-object
